# Putting TV unit on a glass shelf

Tags: television, glass, mount, shelf

I have a TV unit (which weighs about 10 kg) that I want to put on top of the first shelf. As you can see on the photographs, it's already being used as a TV unit but it's too short for viewing distance. That's why I thought I can use the first shelf as a base.

Of course a TV will be mounted on the TV unit itself. I was wondering if the glass can hold the weight from the look of it?

Sorry for the blurry pictures I might provide the spesific dimensions if you want.

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

Edit: I've measured the shelf.
Width is 47 inches, height is about 17 inches. Thickness of the glass is about 25/64 inches (1 cm). On a side note, i's written "tempered glass" on a side of the shelf, which I think is a good thing.

I've tried to take a clearer photograph of the whole thing and marked the metal pipes acting as support.

[image: detailed]
Also here's the link to the TV unit which I'll be locating on top of the shelf.

https://www.amazon.com.tr/gp/aw/d/B086W3J6TN?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title

By the way, the TV which I'll be mounting on this TV unit weights about 22 kg.

Comment: Whether this glass shelf could safely support another unit depends on if the glass is supported in the middle by more legs. Can you please take a full picture of the unit that you have strips showing now? Also take a picture of the new unit you're planning. Measure the length of the existing unit and the new unit, too, please.

Comment: Another alternative, if you're buying the new unit: get one that is tall enough in itself, and repurpose the old unit elsewhere.

Comment: What is the worst that could happen?   (is the question I always ask myself).

Comment: I've edited the question regarding measurements and added a more detailed photograph. Could you please have a look at it again? Thanks you all for all of your answers.